# Computed Property from Child's ViewModel does not update @ObservedObject Parent's ViewModel

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, swiftui, combine

I have a parent view and a child view, each with their own viewModels. The parent view injects the child view's viewModel.

**The parent view does not correctly react to the changes on the child's computed property `isFormInvalid` (the child view does).**

@Published cannot be added to a computed property, and other questions/answers I've seen around that area have not focused on having separate viewModels as this question does. I want separate viewModels to increase testability, since the child view could become quite a complex form.

Here is a file to minimally reproduce the issue:

```
import SwiftUI

extension ParentView {
    final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @ObservedObject var childViewViewModel: ChildView.ViewModel

        init(childViewViewModel: ChildView.ViewModel = ChildView.ViewModel()) {
            self.childViewViewModel = childViewViewModel
        }
    }
}

struct ParentView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel: ViewModel

    init(viewModel: ViewModel = ViewModel()) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }

    var body: some View {
        ChildView(viewModel: viewModel.childViewViewModel)
        .navigationBarTitle("Form", displayMode: .inline)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .confirmationAction) {
                addButton
            }
        }
    }

    private var addButton: some View {
        Button {
            print("======")
            print(viewModel.childViewViewModel.$name)
        } label: {
            Text("ParentIsValid?")
        }
        .disabled(viewModel.childViewViewModel.isFormInvalid) // FIXME: doesn't work, but the actual fields work in terms of two way updating
    }
}

struct ParentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let childVm = ChildView.ViewModel()
        let vm = ParentView.ViewModel(childViewViewModel: childVm)

        NavigationView {
            ParentView(viewModel: vm)
        }
    }
}

// MARK: child view

extension ChildView {
    final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {

        // MARK: - public properties

        @Published var name = ""
        
        var isFormInvalid: Bool {
            print("isFormInvalid")
            return name.isEmpty
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    init(viewModel: ViewModel = ViewModel()) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Name")) {
                nameTextField
            }
            Button {} label: {
                Text("ChildIsValid?: \(String(!viewModel.isFormInvalid))")
            }
            .disabled(viewModel.isFormInvalid)
        }
    }
    
    private var nameTextField: some View {
        TextField("Add name", text: $viewModel.name)
            .autocapitalization(.words)
    }
}

struct ChildView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let vm = ChildView.ViewModel()
        ChildView(viewModel: vm).preferredColorScheme(.light)
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Don't use a computed property for `isFormValid`  Make it  an  `@Published` property and use a `didSet` on the `name` property to set `isFormValid`.

Comment: How would that work with more than one field though?

Comment: You need to create a `validate` function in your model and call it whenever any properties change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computed properties do not trigger any updates. It is the changed to `@Publised` property that triggers an update, when that happens the computed property is reevaluated. This works as expected which you can see in your `ChildView`. The problem you are facing is that `ObservableObject`s are not really designed for chaining (updated to child does not trigger update to the parent. You can workaround the fact by republishing an update from the child: you have subscribe to child's `objectWillChange` and each time it emits manually trigger `objectWillChange` on the parent.

```
extension ParentView {
    final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @ObservedObject var childViewViewModel: ChildView.ViewModel
        private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

        init(childViewViewModel: ChildView.ViewModel = ChildView.ViewModel()) {
            self.childViewViewModel = childViewViewModel
            childViewViewModel
                .objectWillChange
                .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
                .sink { [weak self] _ in
                    self?.objectWillChange.send()
                }
                .store(in: &cancellables)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks. To what extent is this 'working against/around the framework' and do you think this is something that SwiftUI/Combine is missing and would add in the future? I'm trying to gauge how hacky this is and whether I should somehow refactor to avoid this sort of solution.